# Unable to see Selenium Grid java logging windows when started as a scheduled task

Tags: windows, selenium, selenium-grid, windows-server-2016

I have Selenium Grib hub and nodes setup to run in task scheduler on a Windows server 2016 machine.

If I setup this task to run at startup, after I have remoted to the machine, I can see in task manager that **Java(TM) Platform SE binary** is running and browseing to the hub works.....

[image]

...however as you can see there are no logging windows. Typically these are displayed in the taskbar as java windows. Also when running tests, despite seemingly being run, I don't see any browser windows being opened.

I have the following in my batch file

```
cmd /C start/MIN java -jar "C:\Selenium\Grid\selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar" -role hub -timeout 120 -browserTimeout 120
cmd /C start/MIN java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\Selenium\Webdrivers\chromedriver.exe -jar "C:\Selenium\Grid\selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar" -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=firefox,maxInstances=5 -browser browserName=chrome,platform=WIN10,maxInstances=5 -browser browserName="internet explorer",platform=WIN10,maxInstances=1 -port 5555
```

And my scheduled task looks like the following....

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: This is working as expected. When running as a service or scheduled task, windows runs it in [session 0](https://kb.firedaemon.com/support/solutions/articles/4000086228-what-is-session-0-isolation-what-do-i-need-to-know-about-it-) where you cannot interact with it. This ensures that your tasks will not get accidentally tampered with. So what is it that you are trying to achieve to want to see in real time?

Comment: Thanks HaC. The hope was that I would be able to see the tests being ran on the VM whilst a build (CI) was running for debugging purposes. This wouldn't be for every automated build. Once it's setup it's fine to run as 'headless'. I guess I can stop the services and run a batch file that starts the selenium grid hub and nodes manually on the VM, and then point my local machine at it.